# Very precise calculation of the heliocentric position coords (X, Y, Z) the point of coordinates (N/S, W/E degrees) on Earth

Tags: astronomy, algorithms

I need a very precise calculation of the heliocentric position coords (X, Y, Z) the point of coordinates (N/S, W/E degrees) on Earth.

Currently, thanks to the algorithm which generates the position of the planets heliocentric coords I calculate the general position (X, Y, Z) of the Earth.

The problem is that I can not limit myself to the position of the Earth, and I need the position of a point coordinates on Earth.

I must do it's very precise.

Are there any ready-made algorithms for solving this problem?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, you already have the coordinate transformation for the center of Earth and you want to extend that to a coordinate on Earth's surface? Does the algorithm you have take the Moon into account?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that. Yes, I have to take into account the Moon.

Comment: The next steps would be to add a model for the axial precession https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_precession and a terrain model: http://www.opentopography.org/. Do you know what the precision of your data for the center of mass of the planet is? How good is the astronomical data?

Comment: Hmmm... looks like the 18.6 year nutation cycle also causes something like a 500m deviation, if that's important, even though I can't imagine that we actually know the position of Earth's center of mass with that kind of precision in heliocentric coordinates. That would be one part in $10^{12}$ or something!

Comment: 500m deviation? This deviation is cumulative and over time may be even bigger or not? 500m is probably acceptable. As for the technical part I use libraries high precision real number so the error caused the same calculations almost will not.

Comment: I was trying to find sources that mention the systematic and statistical errors for the center of mass coordinates of Earth, but couldn't, so far. The precession is approx. 50" per year and it is cumulative (in the short run), which should add up to hundreds of meters of deviation at the poles per year. Nutation is 17" over a period of 18.6 years and I don't think that any of that is cumulative. The max. deviation is approx. 500m, if I didn't make a mistake. I would think that both effects and possibly even the topography pale in comparison to the orbital element errors of Earth.

Comment: Well ... The only problem is that it is not sure whether the jet on the basis of descriptions on Wikipedia (and other sites) I can reconstruct totally correct algorithm. It can be difficult the more that I'm not an astronomer or physicist. There is some Internet example implementations of this problem, or even pseudocode?

Comment: Just curious... what's your application? I don't assume that you have a spacecraft to Mars that needs navigation code... In case that you do, the usual procedure to get this "right" is to have multiple people code the same problem multiple times independently and then to have another bunch of people write multiple versions of a test bench. By the way... just because you can find some code on the internet doesn't mean it's correct. For an important application you would always have to assume that it's incorrect and then prove that it's correct, first, before using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40489/discussion-between-marek-wolny-and-curiousone).

Comment: Relying on 'high precision real numbers' is asking for trouble. You need to understand numerical methods at least a little bit.

Comment: @JonCuster: The problem isn't numerical precision. The problem is error calculus. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to pretend that we know the position of the Earth in the solar system down to a few meters (or whatever precision the OP is striving for). The only application in which this matters that I can think of is spacecraft navigation and that simply doesn't work this way.